# PowerShell how to incorporate regex in replace command

Tags: regex, linux, windows, powershell, scripting

I have a txt file (TSTTTT.txt) with a string value of :

```
$$FULL_LOAD_DAY=Monday
```

I would like to change it to, through powershell :

```
$$FULL_LOAD_DAY=Tuesday
```

I already know that the regex needed to find my entire string is [regardless of the day]:

```
 \$\$FULL_LOAD_DAY=(\w+)(?=[,.]|$)+
```

I just don't know how to change my usual Powershell command to include regex:

```
(Get-Content C:\Private\TSTTTT.txt).replace('a', 'b') | Set-Content C:\Private\TSTTTT.txt
```

Comment: `'$$FULL_LOAD_DAY=Monday' -replace '(?<=\$\$FULL_LOAD_DAY=)(\w+)(?=[,.]|$)+', 'Tuesday'` seems to do what you're looking for. Note the use of `-replace` which is a regex compatible operator where as the `.replace` string method is not regex compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-replace` operator to use regex in replacing string.

For example, to replace your string with 'b', use the following:

```
(Get-Content C:\Private\TSTTTT.txt) -replace '\$\$FULL_LOAD_DAY=(\w+)(?=[,.]|$)+','b' | Set-Content C:\Private\TSTTTT.txt
```

Comment: thanks, that worked, could I just ask you one thing plz, how do I incorporate my variable in the string will be there after the replace (instead of having the hardcoded tuesday):

$Day = Tuesday


(Get-Content C:\Private\TSTTTT.txt) -replace '\$\$FULL_LOAD_DAY=(\w+)(?=[,.]|$)+','$$FULL_LOAD_DAY=Tuesday' | Set-Content C:\Private\TSTTTT.txt;

(Get-Content C:\Private\TSTTTT.txt) -replace '\$\$OverrideDay=(\w+)(?=[,.]|$)+','$$OverrideDay=Tuesday' | Set-Content C:\Private\TSTTTT.txt

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right your regex can be much simpler ...

```
$Day = 'Tuesday'
(Get-Content C:\Private\TSTTTT.txt) -replace '(?<=\$\$FULL_LOAD_DAY=)(\w+)', $Day |
    Set-Content C:\Private\TSTTTT.txt
```